# How to open a file using matlab and change something in it automatically?

Tags: matlab

I need to open a software and give it a value and then execute it to obtain some results
but the problem is that I have many values and each time I put a value manually which is very time consuming. Is there a way to do this automatically with MATLAB?

Comment: Of course there is. You can open/close, read & write a file e.g. with `fread`, `fwrite`, `fopen`, `fclose` or `fprintf`. Besides, this is way to vague for a more direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: your question title and your actual question are quite different. I'm going to give you ideas to answer your question, not your question title.

you need to find out, whether you can run your software in **batch mode**. That means, you need to be able to control the software from the command-line.

Once you know that, you can use the `system` command of matlab to run the `cmd` from your script.

for example:

```
system( 'mySoftware.exe' -myIndividualParameters )
```

If it's not possible to pass parameters to your software, it may can read text files, which you can create with matlab before.

Anyway, your question is specifying absolutely nothing. You have to give a lot more information: how is your software obtaining parameters? you can it be started? Which format do the parameters need? Do you want matlab to do something with results of your software?

Comment: The software is RETC and because I'm doing this for a friend I don't know what RETC is. I see a lot of words here that I don't know such as batch mode and cmd. I'm gonna search them on the internet. BTW I'm new in stack over flow and this is my first question and I'm so excited.